# Detect when printing has canceled or not using Javascript

Tags: javascript, printing

Is it possible to see when the `onafterprint` the print action has been canceled or completed using JavaScript?

I've tried this:

```js
window.onafterprint = e => {
    console.log("after print");
    console.log(e);
};
```

But in both situations *(cancel and succeed)* the `e` has the same value. When the print has succeeded, I want to load the next item of a queue, else the same item stays. *Note:* The application I'm making looks like the Stack Overflow review queues but with a print option.

Comment: I found this in an article: 'It is not even possible to know, whether document was actually printed or user canceled it.' https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/51737633.html